Finding similar DNA sequence in a specific organism with Biopython's Blast module
I am trying to find a DNA sequence homologous to a given coding sequence in a specific organism (E. fergusoni, to root an E. coli genes phylogeny)
I want to blast one of my focal species' sequence and get back all sequence from E. fergusoni that have between 80% and 98% similarity on the whole segment.
This work prety well on the NCBI online version of blast, by setting "Escherichia fergusonii (taxid:564)" in the "Organism" field. However, I want to automatise this process to be able to run it quickly on a large set of disinct E. coli genes.
I want to use the  NCBIWWW.qblast function from the Blast module with argument "entrez_query" to specify the organism I want to restrain my research to.
This is what I tried :

Blast.email = my_email@email.com
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

sequence_data = open("gene0.fasta").read()
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast(
    program="blastn",
    database="nt",
    sequence=sequence_data,
    # entrez_query = "txid564[Organism]",
    # entrez_query = "Escherichia fergusonii (taxid:564)[Organism]",
    # entrez_query = "txid564[ORGN]",
    # entrez_query = "564[Taxid]",
    format_type="XML",
)

with open("gene0_results.xml", "w") as out_handle:
    out_handle.write(result_handle.read())



for record in NCBIXML.parse(open("gene0_results.xml")): 
    if record.alignments: 
        print("\n") 
        print("query: %s" % record.query[:100]) 
        for align in record.alignments: 
            for hsp in align.hsps: 
                if (hsp.identities/len(hsp.query) < 0.98) and (hsp.identities/len(hsp.query) >= 0.8)  : 
                    print("match: %s " % align.title[:100])
                    print(f"length: {align.length}")
                    print(f"e value: {hsp.expect}")
                    print(f"identity : {hsp.identities/len(hsp.query)} ({hsp.identities} nucleotides over {len(hsp.query)})")
                    print(hsp.query[0:75] + "...")
                    print(hsp.match[0:75] + "...")
                    print(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + "...")

When I run this script without uncommenting the entrez_query arguments, I get the E. coli sequences that are 100% similar to my query, in about 1 mn.
But when I uncomment one of them, I don't get any result at all (I also checked the XML file to see if my later filtering was not the reason), and the request can take up to 20mn. I am looking for the correct syntax to specify the organism with entrez_query (I tried different ones based on what I saw on other posts or what seemed intuitive) but none of them give any result, contrarily to the internet blast version.
I am using Python 3.11 and Biopython 1.83 in a Jupyter Notebook with VSC 1.89.1

This worked for me and matched only those sequences with Escherichia fergusoni in the description line:
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
NCBIWWW.email = "redacted@redacted.edu" # based on https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec178

sequence_data = open("gene0.fasta").read()
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast(
    program="blastn",
    database="nt",
    sequence=sequence_data,
    # entrez_query = "txid564[Organism]",
    # entrez_query = "Escherichia fergusonii (taxid:564)[Organism]",
    entrez_query = "txid564[ORGN]", # best match to https://www.biostars.org/p/439571/#439707
    # entrez_query = "564[Taxid]",
    format_type="XML",
)

with open("gene0_results.xml", "w") as out_handle:
    out_handle.write(result_handle.read())



for record in NCBIXML.parse(open("gene0_results.xml")): 
    if record.alignments: 
        print("\n") 
        print("query: %s" % record.query[:100]) 
        for align in record.alignments: 
            for hsp in align.hsps: 
                if (hsp.identities/len(hsp.query) < 0.98) and (hsp.identities/len(hsp.query) >= 0.8)  : 
                    print("match: %s " % align.title[:100])
                    print(f"length: {align.length}")
                    print(f"e value: {hsp.expect}")
                    print(f"identity : {hsp.identities/len(hsp.query)} ({hsp.identities} nucleotides over {len(hsp.query)})")
                    print(hsp.query[0:75] + "...")
                    print(hsp.match[0:75] + "...")
                    print(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + "...")

I see results listed with matches to the DNA I arbitrarily selected.
It doesn't take 20 minutes; however, it isn't instant either.
You need an email or you get throttled. Your code didn't seen to handle that appropriately? Maybe that was where you were encountering issues? Update what I posted above with your email.
For the taxon identifier I followed the example from this Biostar's post and uncommented your line entrez_query = "txid564[ORGN]".
Other than that, I used your code.
If you want to make it run faster and only want to query one (or a few ) of the Escherichia fergusoni genomes, see the 'Available Notebooks' listed if you go to my blast-binder repo and click on the 'launch binder' badge to get a temporary session in your browser with things already to go. You can essentially just make a database of a genome and search that. It is more efficient because you are essentially running BLAST locally. The later notebooks show integrating with Python better as the earlier ones are just to build up showing it works on the command line.

Thank you very much ! Indeed this solution worked for me (changing NCBIWWW.email to Blast.email and using entrez_query = "txid564[ORGN]"). I don't exactly know why it didn't worked yesterday when I tried it, but I understood why it was taking 20 mn minutes yesterday : I actually forgot to mention that as I am running Python >=3.6 on OSX, I was using import ssl then ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_contextand I think this was doubling the execution time each time I re-ran a the blast query (I fixed it with link )

Thank you ! I am sorry but I didn't provide the complete full context yesterday. It is working now with this syntax but I think the actual reason was because I was bypassing an apparently frequent SSL certificate error with Python >=3.6 on OSX using import ssl then ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context which was allowing me to run the blast query but re-running query seemed to almost double the execution time from 2mn to 4 then 10 ... It was already reported here and solved with the link in comment (certifi library instal).
